# how can I use unnamed Regex groups in C# inside my regex?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

hey so my current regex is `@"(into)(to)add\s[^\s]{1,}\1|\2[^\s]{1,}"` I want the input to be something "add word into/to category" the regex in general works fine but just the `\1|\2` part, I tried using groups and all sorts of solutions but I just can't seem to figure out how I can make it so that the input can be `into` **or** `to`

Can anyone help me out? (this is in C# and using the `Regex` class)

Comment: Please show an example string of input and expected output.

Comment: FYI `{1,}` is just the same as using `+` and `[^\s]` is the same as `\S`

Comment: @PoulBak input can be shown right there in the question "add word into category"

Comment: @juharr I see, I forgot about that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, then you don't need back references to (unnamed) Groups, you can use a simple alternation, like this:

```
@"add \w+ (into|to) \w+"
```

That will select either `into` or `to` in the search string.

**Edit**:

Let's get a Little more 'advanced', using the `optional` sign '`?`':

```
@"add \w+ (in)?to \w+"
```

This will match '`in`' zero or one time, followed by '`to`', so it will match `into` as well as `to`, exactly as the original RegEx.

**Edit2**:

I have a feeling, you want to use a variable inside your RegEx, you can of course do that like this:

```
string search = "into|to";
RegEx regEx = new ReqEx(@"add \w+ (" + search + ") \w+");
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I wanted but this brings me the question, if I did want to use unnamed groups would I use "(into)(to)add \w+ (\1|\2) \w+"?

Comment: No, that would still match 'into' at the start, which is not the case here. Back references match something that has been matched earlier.

Answer (score 0):

From your given example I think you're looking for a regex like `add\s\w+\s(into|to)\s\w+`. Your current regex matches only strings starting with "intoto" wich is probably not what you want.